# phpmyadmin link to modify row

Tags: phpmyadmin

I can't figure out how to create a link to directly access a phpmyadmin page to update a row. This functionality would be very very usefull because in the application I'm building (admin backend) if some row details are missing, I would like to open a new tab with rows details and be able to update and save them (imagine how much time would be saved).

When I right click on modify row button, I get following :

```
http://DOMAIN/pmahost/tbl_change.php?
db=MY_DATABASE
&table=MY_TABLE
&where_clause=`MY_TABLE`.`MY_ROW_ID` = THE_ROW_ID_I_WANT_TO_EDIT
&clause_is_unique=1
&sql_query=SELECT * FROM `MY_TABLE`
&goto=sql.php
&default_action=update
&token=2602b9496f8b45194b630f53b3193591
```

But when I build this url (without token), it brings me to a page to add a row, not to edit selected row. I understand there could be some security issues, but as long as the user connects to phpmyadmin, he should be able to do every action he needs. I can't find any documentation on how phpmyadmin urls are built.

Once again, I can't imagine this is not possible giving the productivity increase that functionality would bring (no need to build interfaces to change database values, direct access to the db !!!) I'm very exited about it, I hope you will be too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is **absolutely good** way to update or insert to the table , but passing *query string parameters* is always risky. It takes some time analyze and to work on this. It is absolutely possible, since php code is open source ,and we can modify it. We will do it . 
thank you

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, let me know when you will have worked on it to **immediately** update to latest version and test it !